# Will the shape of the Loss function change during training?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I have some problem understanding the theory of loss function and hope some one can help me.

Usually when people try to explain gradient descent to you, they will show you a loss function that looks like the very first image in this post [gradient descent: all you need to know](https://hackernoon.com/gradient-descent-aynk-7cbe95a778da). I understand the entire theory of gradient descent is to adjust the weights and minimize the loss function.

My question is, will the shape of the Loss function change during the training or it will just stay remain as the image shown in the above post? I know that the weights are something that we are always tuning so the parameters that determines the shape of the Loss function should be the inputs X={x1,x2,...xn}. Let's make an easy example: suppose our inputs are [[1,2,3,4,5],[5,4,3,2,1]] and labels are [1,0] (Only two training sample for ease, and we are setting the batch size to 1). Then the loss function should be some thing like this for the first training sample

```
L = (1-nonlinear(1*w1+2*w2+3*w3+4*w4+5*w5+b))^2
```

and for the second training sample the loss function should be:

```
L = (0-nonlinear(5*w1+4*w2+3*w3+2*w4+1*w5+b))^2
```

Apparently, these two loss functions doesn't looks like the same if we plot them so does that mean the shape of the Loss function are changing during training? Then why are people still using that one image ( A point that slides down from the Loss function and finds the global minima) to explain the gradient descent theory?

**Note**: I'm not changing the loss function, the loss function are still mean square error. I'm trying to say that the shape of the Loss function seems to be changing.

I know where my problem comes from! I thought that we are not able to plot a function such as f(x,y) = x*y without any constant in it, but we actually could! I searched the graph on google for f(x,y)=x*y and truly we can plot them out! So now I understand, as long as we get the lost function, we can get the plot! Thanks guys

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence off-topic here; questions on general ML theory & methodology should be posted at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and/or [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

The function stays the same. The point of Gradient Decent is to find the lowest point on a given loss function that you define.

Comment: Yeah I know the function stays the same but from the example I gave, the shape seems to be changing isn't it? the Loss function are always mean square error

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the loss function you are training to minimize does not change throughout the course of a training session. The flaw in reasoning is that you are assuming that the loss function is characterized by weights of the network, when in fact the weights of that network are a sort-of input to the loss function.

To clarify, let us assume we are predicting some `N`-dimensional piece of information and we have a ground truth vector, call it `p`, and a loss function `L` taking in a prediction vector `p_hat` which we define as

```
L(p_hat) := norm(p - p_hat).
```

This is a very primitive (and quite ineffective) loss function, but it is one nonetheless. Once we begin training, this loss function will be the function that we will try to minimize to get our network to perform the best with respect to. Notice that this loss function will attain different values for different inputs of `p_hat`, this does not mean the loss function is changing! In the end, the loss function will be an `N`-dimensional hypersurface in an `N+1`-dimensional hyperspace that stays the same no matter what (similar to the thing you see in the image where it is a `2`-dimensional surface in a `3`-dimensional space).

Gradient descent tries to find a minimum on this surface that is constructed by the loss function, but we do not really know what the surface looks like as a whole, instead, we find out small things about the surface by evaluating the loss function as the values of `p_hat` we give it.

Note, this is all a huge oversimplification, but can be a useful way to think about it getting started.

Comment: I know , but from my example above, in two different batches, the Loss function are truly changing even though they are both using mean square error.

Comment: No, the loss function is not changing: you are evaluating the loss function at different values.

Comment: Yeah thanks! I know where my problem comes from! I thought that we are not able to plot a function such as f(x,y) = x*y without any constant in it, but we actually could! I searched the graph on google for f(x,y)=x*y and truly we can plot them out! So now I understand, as long as we get the lost function, we can get the plot! Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

A [Loss Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_function) is a metric that measures the distance from your predictions to your targets.

The ideia is to choose the weighs so your predictions are close to your targets, that is, your model learned/memorized the input.

The loss function should usually not be changed during training, because the minimum in the original function might not coincide with the new one, so the gradient descent's work is lost.

Comment: Yeah I know the function stays the same but from the example I gave, the shape seems to be changing isn't it? the Loss function are always mean square error

Comment: The loss isn't changing, you're just partially evaluating it. Your argument would also imply that `f(2, y) = 2*y` and `f(3, y) = 3*y` aren't the same function, but hey, they are **both** `f(x, y) = x*y`.

Comment: Yeah thanks! I know where my problem comes from! I thought that we are not able to plot a function such as f(x,y) = x*y without any constant in it, but we actually could! I searched the graph on google for f(x,y)=x*y and truly we can plot them out! So now I understand, as long as we get the lost function, we can get the plot! Thanks guys